# How to disable Struts validation under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, html, struts, struts-validation

The problem I have is that I need to disable struts validation when selecting certain conditions that will leave input boxes disabled and blank.

Leaving these inputs empty causes the validation to fail which is not what I need

Comment: I was hoping that there was an easy way to do this from within Struts (like using validwhen) without modifying the server side java but this does not seem possible. 
Giving the answer to Pat as that was close enough to what I finally implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a property on your form when you trigger these conditions and then check for that in your validator:

```
if(!form.isSkipValidation()){
   // validation goes here
}
```

If you're triggering these skip validation conditions with javascript, you can set this property with a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="skipValidation" value="false"/>
```